# Add a non-georeferenced image at a defined location - not a georeferencing question

Tags: qgis

I have a set of coordinates that represent seabed sample locations (loaded as delimited text). I have a .PDF of the geotechnical results (soil profile below each location) for each station. I have already linked the .PDF as an attachment so I can open the file when I click the hyperlink for each target.
What I would like to do is have an excerpt of the .PDF displayed at each target location, see mock-up below. Is this possible? The .PDF represents a Vertical profile of the soils, so isn't something that can be georeferenced in the normal way as it is the data (Z direction) below the target point.
Can it be somehow added like the target Label?
Is there a way to do it as 3D view?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an image as a symbol for your point layer.
In the layer properties go to symbology tab and change from simple marker to **Raster Image Marker**.

[image]

You can use a field pointing to the image file path. Change the size of your image as you need it. This will place your pdf in the center of your coordinates. If you want you can change the offset in this same symbology tab. If needed you can also add a simple marker in order to see both, the image and a point symbol.

As for the 3D map, you could calculate a field/fields with the profile data and use this fields to extrude a cylinder.

Comment: This works, to get the same .pdf for all locations. I'm struggling to direct it to a different .pdf for each location. Any advice?

Comment: You need to generate a field in your point layer pointing to each pdf and then, use this field in the highlighted part of the image

Answer (score 1):

Create a point layer from your CSV. In the layer properties, go to the tab named `Actions` and create a new action, clicking the green `+` icon.

Select the type of the action you want to use. You might provide an URL, Python code or system specific commands. You can also use the `Insert` field below the `Action text` field to insert values dynamically generated by QGIS expressions, e.g. based on attribute values. In your case, you might want to provide an URL or local file path to the pdf, probably complemented with an information about the clicked coordinates, based on an expression (attribute values or based on the coordinate values of the current geometry).

[image]